# How to reference to emberJS controller from another view

Tags: ember.js

I'm using ember tools for my app. Now I want to add a TextField to trigger a search in my controller, like in [this example.](http://alg.github.io/talks/emberjs/#/title) This is the controller and view:

**ProductsController:**

```
var ProductsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  search: function(query) {
    console.log(query);
  }
});

module.exports = ProductsController;
```

**SearchFieldView:**

```
var SearchFieldView = Ember.TextField.extend({
  insertNewline: function() {
    var query = this.get('value');
    App.ProductsController.search(query);
  }
});
module.exports = SearchFieldView;
```

But whenever the textfield is changing I've got the error that the `App.ProductsController` has no method `search`. So I've got the feeling it is not the one I have created but the generated one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.get('controller') to get the current controller instance. or if u need a another controller instance you can use this.get('controller').get('controllers.anothercontroller').. [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/utuqut/1/edit)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've got it. `App.ProductsController` isn't the instance of the actual controller and as all views under route have the same controller its just `this.get('controller')`

```
var SearchFieldView = Ember.TextField.extend({
  insertNewline: function() {
    var query = this.get('value');
    this.get('controller').search(query);
  }
});
module.exports = SearchFieldView;
```